# Python command line (too few arguments)

Tags: python

I have a problem with my python system call. I have set up my python, path and pathext.

These commands work on my computer

```
run.py
python runWithParamater.py parameterExample.txt
```

but if I run:

```
runWithParamater.py parameterExample.txt
```

The interpreter will return "error: too few arguments".

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: how would `runWithParamater.py` run? have you run `chmod +x` on the file to make it executable ?

Comment: Does the file start with the line `#!/usr/bin/env python` or similar?

Comment: You have to make the file executable with `chmod +x` first

Comment: I added #!C:/Anaconda/python.exe. Now it works.thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `runWithParameter.py` probably expects 3 arguments including `python`.

Comment: I'm confused. For example, if I run 
"python runWithParamater.py parameterExample.txt" -> 2 arguments right?

If I run :
"runWithParamater.py parameterExample.txt" -> 2 arguments also or 1? 

Sorry I'm outside, can't try it right now.

Comment: `python runWithParamater.py parameterExample.txt` is three arguments, `runWithParamater.py parameterExample.txt` is two.

Comment: so the argument is decreased by 1.  Is it possible to solve this without changing the code/the validation?

Comment: You can make an `if` statement that considers the amount of arguments. Or you can coerce the implied `python` argument with a `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Answer (score 1):

Your program `runWithParameter.py` needs `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of it. Then, in your shell, type `chmod +x runWithParameter.py`. From there, you can simply type `runWithParameter.py` and it will run.

**Example**:

`foo.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Hello World'
```

And depending on your `$PATH`, you can type `foo.py` to run it. Else, you will have to precede it with `./`

```
bash-3.2$ chmod +x foo.py
bash-3.2$ ./foo.py
Hello World
bash-3.2$
```

Or, if you are going to be running this function locally, you can define a function:

```
bash-3.2$ function foo.py(){
> ./foo.py
> }
bash-3.2$ foo.py
Hello World
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: My bad, meant `chmod +x`. Typo.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham nope.

Comment: @A.J. Depends on your PATH.  Normally putting "." in your PATH is considered a bad  idea for security reasons, but people do it....

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i'm using linux

Comment: yes, that's the correct answer. I missed #!C:/Anaconda/python.exe (running on windows) thx!

Comment: @DennyDharmawan no problem, if this answer helped you, would you mind accepting (and/or +1-ing) it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I missed #!C:/Anaconda/python.exe(running on windows).
By adding it, my arguments are counted correctly (without decreasing one if I don't use python.exe on my command)

Is there any possible solution without changing the code though? I got these scripts from a library and the default one is : "#!/usr/bin/env python". It's quite a cumbersome thing to do to add that line into all the scripts.