# Argument parser error: too few arguments

Tags: python

I am trying to pass over a file from the command line to use in my python code, I am using the command like so:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\py>twitter_checker.py -u C:\xampp\htdocs\py\test.txt
```

Now when I run that command I get the following error

> usage: twitter_checker.py [-h] u
>
> twitter_checker.py: error: too few arguments

How can I fix this so I can pass my .txt file over to use in the `open()`

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_

# Check if twitter usernames exist or are available

import argparse as ap
import requests

def args():
    """ Get the arguments passed from the CLINE """
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("u", help="The text file with all your usernames in")
    return parser.parse_args()

def checker():
    """Loop through lines and check for available usernames"""
    argslist = args()
    usernames = open(argslist.u, "r")
    lines = usernames.readlines()
    usernames.close()

    for line in lines:
        url = "https://twitter.com/" + line
        check = requests.get(url)
        if check.status_code == 404:
            print line + ' is avaialble'
        else:
            print line + ' is taken...'
checker()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032916/python-command-line-too-few-arguments?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parser.add_argument` is incorrect for what you are putting as the argument.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\py>twitter_checker.py -u C:\xampp\htdocs\py\test.txt
```

Should be using:

```
parser.add_argument("-u", help="The text file with all your usernames in")
```

Notice `-u` instead of `u`... switch one or the other (either the argument, or the parser).